# Is this an encoding issue with sqlite date or c#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, date-format

I have a job that runs and records a date at the start and end of a process. However when the application loads it needs to fetch the data for the previous run. But every-time it throws an exception saying: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

And when I look at the stored data of course I find for instance "2013-41-10 10:08"

previously set thus

```
string jobsDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM");
```

The statement I am using is:

```
bool IsInserted = db.Update("UPDATE jobs SET JobLastRun ='" + jobsDate + "', jobStatus = '" + status + "' WHERE rowid = " + rowid );
```

db.Update is largely redundant but is here for posterity

```
    public bool Update(String updateQuery)
    {
        Boolean returnCode = true;
        try
        {
            //dbl.AppendLine(sql);
            dbl.AppendLine(updateQuery);
            this.ExecuteNonQuery(updateQuery);
        }
        catch(Exception crap)
        {
            OutCrap(crap);
            returnCode = false;
        }
        return returnCode;
    }


    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
    {
        SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection);
        cnn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
        mycommand.CommandText = sql;
        int rowsUpdated = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
        return rowsUpdated;
    }
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this an encoding issue?

No. You have the minutes and months format specifiers the wrong way around. It should be

```
  string jobsDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                                                ^^       ^^
 MM = Months
 mm = minutes
 HH = hours in 24 hour clock
 hh = hours in 12 hour clock
```

A good reference is: [String Formatting in C#](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

Comment: the only other spec I could find however showed everything in UPPERCASE (both minutes and months) which of course wasn't right. Any way thanks for you help!

Comment: Hello Mitch - Before that previous comment, I started with a comment that said: "of course you're right" and then explained that I got the formatting information directly off of the sqlite site. But that seems to have disappeared - is that common in here? (it is not the first time I have seen text vanish into the either) it was relevant because it explained how I was misled which might help others.

Comment: @Andrew Seabrook: perhaps add an edit/update to your question with the info?

Answer (score 0):

`2013-41-10 10:08` is not a correct datetime.

It was stored that way because of your formatstring here:

`string jobsDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM");`

In a formatstring 'MM' means Months, and `mm` means minutes, so the correct string should be:

`string jobsDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");`

Comment: Yes Mitch already pointed out the Error! but thanks for you effort.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an encoding issue?

**definitely not**. This is your format that is causing you issues.

if you look at your code you will find that

```
2013-41-10 10:08
```

41 definitely cannot be months. You are getting this because of small `mm` which means minutes. For months you need to change it to **MM** and for mintues you need to change it to `mm` after `HH`.
you need to change it like this

```
string jobsDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");  //note the capital MM for months and small mm for mintues
```

Comment: Yes Mitch already pointed out the error! but thanks for you effort....41 definitely cannot be month...you dont say.

Comment: For your information I had it the correct way round originally and it was failing when I looked at the Sqlite documentation it explicitly says mm is months. so I changed it and it was still failing. After trying various ways I asked the question here and Mitch reaffirmed my original understanding. It turned out it was actually failing at another formatting point where I had two spaces instead of one, between date and time. Oh well got there in the end!